# Can't get query to show on web page

Tags: php, wordpress, mysqli

Working on my first mysqli data query. I have done a ton of reading, but I am not understanding something... or apparently many things

I get no errors, but I get a blank page. I can get a positive return if I use a straight php page such as example.php, so I believe the connection and basic query can work. This is in a wordpress site.

The results should look like 
    River        Fish
    Alsea        Steelhead
    Applegate    Fall Chinook
    Etc.         Etc.

I will add more columns once I get basic functionality

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","database","password","username");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql="SELECT River, Fish FROM coastal1 ORDER BY River";

if ($result=mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
// Fetch one and one row
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){
echo $row[0].'  '.$row[1];
}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);
}
?>
```

Comment: no errors and a blank screen means syntax errors. Use/enable error reporting and `mysqli_error($con)` in your query.

Comment: Can you add this line in top of php `error_reporting(-1);` and tell what error it shows

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried it berfore // Free result set and no change

Comment: @TamilSelvan I tried it at line 2 and again at line 4 and no change.

Comment: @Mike did you see my answer below, where to add `or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con))` for your query?

Comment: @Mike, you might want to add  `ini_set("display_errors", 1);` as well.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I added as per the example and no change.

Comment: @Mike am wondering if it's because of it being a wordpress site; it uses different methods and variables to connect

Comment: @Fred-ii- that is a concern I have also. I should chase that angle the Host and WP

Comment: ok..open browser console and refresh the page and see network tab, is it return 200 or 500 or 400 status OR just echo some text in the page , i think the query return null

Answer (score 3):

This line:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","database","password","username");
```

"database" goes last

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database");
```

View the manual on `mysqli_connect()`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

I.e.:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
```

and add `or die mysqli_error($con)` to `mysqli_query()`

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

Comment: I wonder if he just made a mistake transcribing it since many hosts have the same name for user and database.

Comment: @Devon I'm pretty sure that what they posted is an example.

Comment: @Fred The username and database name are the same. Not real secure, but I don't want to change anything till after I get it working.

Comment: @Mike I've made a slight edit to show you how to add error reporting in your site/page. that might yield something.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried it and no change. I'm thinking it is probably tied to wordpress.

Comment: @Mike I'm also under that impression. Did you try error reporting and if so, did it yield anything? same thing for `or die mysqli_error($con)` added  to `mysqli_query()` your query may be failing; worth a shot.

Comment: @MIke please provide your database structure with the example......it will help to find the real issue...